# Youtube Data API V3 error message - Quota exceeded even though my usage is less than 2%

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am getting the following error when I am trying to upload a video file though Youtube data API.

"The service youtube has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."

Following are the quota information currently on my project.

[Quota usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9J8Q.png)

Please help me to understand what are the reasons behind this error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to the YouTube Data api its [quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) costs.

If it had been you would have seen this error message

> quotaExceeded (403)    quotaExceeded   The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.

This error is realted to a limitation with in YouTube itself. A user can max upload X videos to YouTube per day depending upon their region / location.

## Support [Common uploading errors](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/10383400?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdaily-upload-limit-reached-you-can-upload-more-videos-in-hours)

[image]

No they have not documented the exact number of videos you can upload that's probably because they want the ability to change it without having to remember to change the documentation